# Changing a divs content from within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following page layout

```
<div id="userscore" >test</div>
<iframe name="frameContent" id="frameContent" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" />
```

The iFrame gets its content dynamically including its javascript.

When I try to access userscore from within the iFrame

```
console.log(window.parent.document.getElementById('user-score'));
```

I get in the console

```
<div id="userscore" >test</div>
```

When I try to use

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('user-score').html('Change the content');
```

I get

```
Object [object HTMLDivElement] has no method 'html'
```

Is there a way around this? Or can anybody shed some light as to what is going on.

Comment: .html() is jQuery method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A DOM-element doesn't have a method `.html()`. That method is an extension often seen in JavaScript-libraries like jQuery.

When using plain JavaScript you have to set the `.innerHTML` property if you want to alter the content of the element.

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('user-score').innerHTML = "New content";
```